# CSS: vertical-align multiple text sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a text line that has multiple font sizes in it. I want all the text to be aligned to the middle of the .line1 element. I used `vertical-align:middle` but it doesn't do the trick. Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tWxdT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erase all vertical-align in css. and give product_mark_bg a vertical-align:baseline

Comment: vertical-align always affects the children of the object it is given to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me in Google Chrome as well, but may I recommend using d`isplay: table-cell;` in your CSS as well? If not even that then scrap using Vertical-Align and try having equal amounts of Padding via the Top and Bottom for your HTML Tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the line-height to get better alignment of differently sized text. Not sure it's what you are looking for, but adding a line-height of 2.2em in the example centered the text a bit differently.